# List, Linkedlist, Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

About the List, Linkedlist and Arraylist, which one is a one way list and which one is Doubly-linked list?
And how could we reverse it?

Comment: List is interface. Are you sure you checked the API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
  An [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)) that merely defines behavior of lists.

  - [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
    A `List` implementation, backed by an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure). It is not a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).
  - [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
    A `List` implementation, backed by an implementation of a [doubly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list).

If you want a single-linked list, you'll have to write it yourself.

I should point out that making a single linked list that implements [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is not easy. It requires you to have a [`ListIterator<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), and part of the `ListIterator` specification is that you can traverse in either direction with methods [`hasPrevious`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#hasPrevious--), [`previous`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous--), and [previousIndex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previousIndex--). So to keep it both efficient and true to the single linked list mantra would be very difficult.

Answer (score 4):

You can reverse any collection using `Collections.reverse(..)`. `LinkedList` (and any `Deque`) has `descendingIterator()`